# WP Job Manager Wordpress Plugin Issue

Tags: wordpress

I've just inherited a Wordpress site with a WP Job Manager plugin in the Jobify Theme. I've figured most of it out, but the "Apply for Job" button seems to be outside the form:

```
<aside class="job_listing-widget default-widget">
<div class="job-type full-time term-2">Full Time</div>
</aside>
<aside class="job_listing-widget default-widget">
<div class="job_application application">
<input type="button" class="application_button button" value="Apply for job" />
<div class="application_details">
<div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f2210-p2560-o1" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
<div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
<form action="/job/salesperson-commission-only/#wpcf7-f2210-p2560-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="2210" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.7" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f2210-p2560-o1" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="b6c957a34d" />
</div>
<p>Your Full Name (required)<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </p>
<p>Your Email (required)<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </p>
<p>CV & Cover Letter<br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap file-01"><input type="file" name="file-01" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" /></p>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form></div>       
</div>
</div>
</aside>
```

Is there any way to edit this? If so where please??

The URL: http://jamesrecruitmentservices.co.uk/job/salesperson-commission-only/

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? The "Apply for Job" button is the 6th line down in your code.

Comment: Absolutely, but it isn't active, so I'm wondering where the code is to edit it to link to the "Apply for Job" page. Any ideas?

Comment: It's either in a plugin or maybe in you function.php file?

Comment: OK, does anyone know how top make this button active? I'm sure it must be in one of the php files, but I'm afraid I can't decipher it. There must be a default setting to make it active, otherwise, why put it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Apply" button usually in

`job-application.php (job_manager/job-application.php)`

script, at least, by default. Try to check there.

Comment: Thank you. Got it.,